# Grouping data based on month-year in pandas and then dropping all entries except the latest one- Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-science

```
 Below is my example dataframe
    Date       Indicator  Value
0   2000-01-30  A          30
1   2000-01-31  A          40
2   2000-03-30  C          50
3   2000-02-27  B          60
4   2000-02-28  B          70
5   2000-03-31  C          90
6   2000-03-28  C          100
7   2001-01-30  A          30
8   2001-01-31  A          40
9   2001-03-30  C          50
10  2001-02-27  B          60
11  2001-02-28  B          70
12   2001-03-31  C          90
13   2001-03-28  C          100


Desired Output
Date        Indicator Value
2000-01-31   A          40
2000-02-28   B          70
2000-03-31   C          90
2001-01-31   A          40
2001-02-28   B          70
2001-03-31   C          90
```

I want to write a code that groups data by particular month-year and then keep the entry of latest date in that particular month-year and drop the rest. The data is till year 2020

I was only able to fetch the count by month-year. I am not able to drop create a proper code that helps to group data as per month-year and indicator and get the correct results

Comment: Is `50` correct ? Because last datetime is `2000-03-31`, not `2000-03-30`

Comment: Sorry..My bad.. It should be 2000-03-31. You are correct

Comment: No problem ;) Be free edit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for months periods, aggregate index of maximal date per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and then pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print (df['Date'].dt.to_period('m'))
0     2000-01
1     2000-01
2     2000-03
3     2000-02
4     2000-02
5     2000-03
6     2000-03
7     2001-01
8     2001-01
9     2001-03
10    2001-02
11    2001-02
12    2001-03
13    2001-03
Name: Date, dtype: period[M]
```

---

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('m'))['Date'].idxmax()]
print (df)
         Date Indicator  Value
1  2000-01-31         A     40
4  2000-02-28         B     70
5  2000-03-31         C     90
8  2001-01-31         A     40
11 2001-02-28         B     70
12 2001-03-31         C     90
```

Comment: the above works fine.. But I have multiple years in date column. The one which I gave was just a sample. If you can help with the dates with multiple year it would be great.

Comment: @PriteshChoksi - hmmm, there is used month periods for working with mutiple years, for you not working?

Comment: @PriteshChoksi - Can you add this data to question? Because bad formating in commnets

Comment: @PriteshChoksi - Can you change data by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62016305/edit) for see what is expected output if different years? Thanks.

Comment: @PriteshChoksi - Not sure what is problem, but my solution working for me like you need.

Comment: it is working. There was a minor error from my side. Thanks a lot